# How do implement a DropdownButton using Getx in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, flutter-getx

I am trying to implement a DropdownButton with two dropdownmenuitems, spanish and english.

I want a user to select a language and will send this back to getx translations in order to change the app's language.

Here is my controller:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class DropdownController extends GetxController {
  String selectedValue;

  var language = <String>['English', 'Espanol'];

  void onSelected(String value) {
    selectedValue = value;
  }
}
```

Here is my settings page

```
class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<DropdownController>(builder: (controller) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
          Text('Select Language: '),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          DropdownButton<String>(
              hint: Text('Language'),
              value: controller.selectedValue,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                controller.onSelected(newValue);
              },
              elevation: 10,
              items: [
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text("English"),
                  value: controller.selectedValue,
                ),
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text("ESpanol"),
                  value: controller.selectedValue,
                ),
              ]),
        ]),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
class DropdownController extends GetxController {
    String? selectedValue;

    var language = <String>['English', 'Espanol'];

    void onSelected(String value) {
    selectedValue = value;

    update();

    print(selectedValue);
    changeLanguage(selectedValue);
  }

  changeLanguage(String? selectedLanguage) {
     switch (selectedLanguage) {
     case 'English':
       Get.updateLocale(Locale('en_US'));
       print('Changed to En');
       break;
     case 'Espanol':
       Get.updateLocale(Locale('en_US'));
       print('Changed to Es');
       break;
     default:
       Get.updateLocale(Locale('en_US'));
       print('Fallback to En');
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

Settings page:

```
class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return GetBuilder<DropdownController>(builder: (controller) {
        return Scaffold(
           body: Column(children: [
             Text('Select Language: '),
             SizedBox(height: 10.0),
             DropdownButton<String>(
               hint: Text('Language'),
               value: controller.selectedValue,
               onChanged: (newValue) {
               controller.onSelected(newValue!);
               },
               elevation: 10,
               items: [
                 DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text("English"),
                  value: 'English',
                 ),
                 DropdownMenuItem(
                   child: Text("ESpanol"),
                   value: 'Espanol',
                 ),
              ]),
           ]),
         );
      });
    }
  }
```